# How to get order ID in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

In magento admin dashboard, the order id displayed is of the form #10001011. In the URL, I can see something similar to

```
http://ZZZ.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/17/key/42311084d2b66e35a64702bbe47d2901/
```

Note that order_id is 17 in the URL. How do I get that ID? what function in magento that will return the actual system id 17? I am trying to do some adjustment to an extension and for some reason it is using 17 instead of #10001011 to generate a download URL for the order.

Comment: Has this answered your question?  if so, please accept an answer so the question can be closed.  If not, please provide more information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Like most entities in Magento, orders have two types of unique identifiers.  There is the `increment_id` which is displayed to users as the Order ID and there is the entity_id also simply called ID. This `entity_id` is what you're seeing in the url.  It is the primary key of the `sales_flat_order` table and generally used as the internal, private id.

`$order->getId()`  should get you the internal entity_id, and `$order->getIncrementId()`  should get you the Order ID you see in the Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Order_id is the internal Magento order ID

Order increment ID is the ID which you communicate to your customer

To get what you want:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
$Incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the value from the URL through getRequest(). In this case:

$order_id=(int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');